# Adding jQuery to forms with the same model in MVC3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to have two submission forms with similar functionality on the same view, where each form is strongly typed to the same model. I then am trying to add a datepicker to the same input on both forms, but I am unsure of how to do this. Here is my code:

```
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm(...
                        new { id = "editScheduleForm" }))
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input 
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime)
    </div>
}
```

...

```
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm(...
                        new { id = "addScheduleForm" }))
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime)
    </div>
}
```

Both of these forms are in their own strongly-typed partial views. I naturally tried simply adding the datepicker in jQuery to both partial views, like so:

```
$(function () {
    $("#StartTime").datepicker();
});
```

But it unsurprisingly only worked for one of the inputs. I have been trying to use the HTML id that I added to both Ajax form declarations (e.g. editScheduleForm and addScheduleForm), but am unsure of how to do this. Any suggestions?

**Solution:**
As scottm suggested, I looked through documentation for using a custom editor template. I read this, detailing functionality I didn't know existed:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407399.aspx

Here, you can specify a template, and then add a parameter for the htmlFieldName, which is specifically designed to circumvent the problem I was happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a class to the inputs in your editor template. Then you can then use the class as the jQuery selector.

Add a file called `DateTime.cshtml` under `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`, and add the following:

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "date" })
```

Then add this jQuery to the page.

```
$(function () {
    $(".date").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: It would be great if this worked, but I don't think I can hand-set the class from an `@Html.BeginForm`. The outputted HTML already has a class, like so: `<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Start Time field is required." id="StartTime" name="StartTime" type="text" value="07/23/2012 12:00:00 AM" />` I tried using your addition, but MVC ignored the new code.

Comment: @c0nn you can further define how your editor templates are rendered by adding a .cshtml file in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`. Here's an example that does exactly what you are looking for: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[The ID must be unique in a document.](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id)

Never rely on multiple ids on a page working correctly. Matter of fact, despite what most examples in blogs do, you should hardly ever use ids as jquery selectors.

Like @scottm said. You should use classes to tag items which you want to be widget-ized.

Here's a simplistic bit of code so you can create jq ui widgets declaratively:

```
$(function() {

  $('[data-usewidget]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), widget = $this.data('usewidget');
    $.fn[widget] && $this[widget]();
  });

});
```

Then in your html

```
<input name=startTime data-usewidget=datepicker />
```